# Git commands for getting the latest changes into local

Tags: git

Currently I am working in a branch called keyfeature.
Now I need to get the latest changes from develop. Can anyone say the steps line by line.

I think:

1. git add my changes in to branch I created>>git add .
2. git commit my changes>> git commit -m "new feature"
3. push my code>>git push keyfeature

after this step, what am I supposed to do?
I want my changes and the lastest changes from develop branch

Comment: Could you try to research the question before asking it? Simply googling, or even looking around in the GitHub docs, or whatever server you use.

Answer (score 2):

```
git pull origin develop
```

(https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

You could also use a git with GUI like listed under https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux. It makes every change visible and you can easily switch between branches and create stashes.